# What is double(C++) in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, types, double

What is the `double` type(C++) in C#?

```
double experience;
```

At first,I thought its `UInt32`,but its not.
How to declare it in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a question that is dependent upon the particular C++ compiler implementation you are using.  The double type can be either 4 or 8 bytes according to the C++ standard.  Most compilers do use 8 bytes though.  Here are the closest representations

- 4 bytes: float
- 8 bytes: double

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx

Comment: and 16 bytes: decimal

Also of note, float and double are IEEE, decimal is not.

Comment: decimal floating point is IEEE nowadays. Thank IBM; they've managed to standardize their mainframe stuff.

Comment: THe C++ standard does not specify 4 or 8 bytes at all. It sets some requirements on minimum ranges and precision. But 7 bytes with 9 bits each would be OK.

Answer (score 3):

It is just `double` or `Double`. More specific `double` is a C# specific alias for `System.Double`.

Answer (score 1):

Double in C# is Double.

double var1 = 0.123;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the question is. A `double` in C# is the same as a `double` in C++. `double` is not an integral number in any mainstream language that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember much about C++, but there is a `double` type in C#.

If you just want larger whole numbers, though, look at `long`.

Answer (score 0):

C# has the double type as well.

```
double experience;
```

should compile and work just fine in C#.